# create vector with new elements

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

so I have the following

```
vector<vector< tuple<string, double>*>*>* graph;
```

a 2d vector, with a tuple of string and double.
I want to initialize the graph(2d vector) with a certain size and
a new vector< tuple<string, double>*>,  in each of the element of the big (outside)vector

and I used the following line

```
graph = new vector<vector<tuple<string, double>*>*>(67, new vector< tuple<string,double>*>());
```

This thing works but when I tried to free it I found out that all new vectors I created are of the
same vector.
meaning, all the elements point to the same vector. I get why this is happening but
is there a way of initialize all the vectors without having to do the for loop, ie

```
for(int i....)
    graph->push_back(new vector< tuple<string,double>*>);
```

Comment: What a reason of dealing with pointers?

Comment: Yeah, pointers here is bound to be something you'll *instantly* regret. It's especially inappropriate for a single `double`.

Comment: That argument to `new` is evaluated once, so yes, you'll get *N* copies of the identical object. This is because the pointer is copied. If you were using non-pointer versions of same it could copy them to *different* instances.

Comment: hi, I use all those pointers because I tend to allocate everything on the heap.
I don't know how many vectors I am going to need, could be hundreds. so I allocate everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem summary:

In the line

```
graph = new vector<vector<tuple<string, double>*>*>(67, new vector< tuple<string,double>*>());
```

constructor 3 of `std::vector` is used ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector))
This will evaluate `new vector<tuple<string,double>*>()` *once*, then create a vector with `67` copies of this pointer.

#### Solution:

Don't use pointers unless you have a really good reason to do so. Use

```
vector<vector<tuple<string, double>>> graph;
```

then you could simply do

```
graph.resize(67);
```

to insert 67 default constructed values. No pointers needed.

Maybe you are used to languages where `new` is frequently used, but you shouldn't do that in C++. `std::vector` and `std::string` are fairly small objects that manage an underlying dynamic array. Creating pointers to them is usually not what you want and might also decrease performance.